# Show total for whole group in Highcharts 'stacked & grouped column' layout

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[Here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped) is the basic demo for Highcharts Stacked & Grouped column layout. The tooltip shows the total for the stack using this call...

```
this.point.stackTotal
```

...however, there are 2 stacks in the group. How do I display the total for all stacks in the group. Something like...

```
this.point.groupTotal
```

...would be ideal, but that doesn't work

Comment: Such sum doesn't exist. You need to sum stacks within the group in the tooltip [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding an extra parameter to your tooltip function: `shared:true` and adding some extra code to sum up all the values within a  grouped stack

Look at this example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ywtw7jtm/)

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },

        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of fruits'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>',
                sum = 0;               
                $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                    s += '<br/>'+ point.series.name +': '+
                        point.y;
                    sum += point.y;
                });                
                s += '<br/>Sum: '+sum               
                return s;
            },
            shared: true
        },


        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
            stack: 'male'
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
            stack: 'male'
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
            stack: 'female'
        }, {
            name: 'Janet',
            data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
            stack: 'female'
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That does work but I want the tooltip to show just the value of 1) the one youre hovererd over 2)the total of that stack 3)the total of that group. For some reason adding the shared parameter doesnt allow me to call the value of the hovered block ( eg.  this.series.name )

Comment: I do not know if that is possible because you only get the stacked value of 1 bar chart by not using the shared property. In order to make this grouped stacked total value visible you will need the shared property. So I do not think you can manage that. If I where you I should ask this question at the forum of highcharts @bboybeatle

Comment: When using shared tooltip, then `this.series` doesn't exist. Instead use `this.points[index].series`. More info about shared formatting in the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.formatter) - (`this.series` vs `this.points[i].series`)

Comment: @PawełFus is there anything comparable to the `points` object outside of the tooltip formatter? Example, I want to calculate a dynamic average of the grouped columns, and add a line series with a point for each group. Hoping to avoid looping through each series for each point if I don't have to.

Comment: Grouped or stacked? For stacked, there are stacks in `chart.yAxis[i]` object, but for grouped.. unfortunately. Groups are calculated on a series level, not on a point (a series sets x-offset for all points). If you need to calculate a dynamic average, then don't you need to loop over all points anyway? To be clear: `points` in tooltip formatter are searched on-the-fly according to x+y mouse position for each of the series.